# r- MICE package getting standardized betas from lm

Tags: r, r-mice

I have a dataset that is missing values. I imputed using the mice package and ran my linear model using lm and pool for the results. I only get unstandardized beta weights. Is there a way to get standardized beta weights?

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways in which you can do so (which I know of), there can be many:

**1) First method:**

You need to first scale your data, so assume you imputed your data first then you can do as following:
**A toy example:**

```
mtcars1 <- mtcars[,c("mpg", "disp", "hp", "wt", "qsec", "drat")]
mtcars_scaled <- data.frame(sapply(mtcars1, scale), stringsAsFactors=F) ##scaling for standardization,
model_fit_st <- lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + drat, data=mtcars_scaled)
```

Here model_fit_st is your standardized result but it does however having the intercept(which is kind of odd, the reason being that we supplied it using lm, it will generate an intercept), however if you compare it with `QuantPsyc::lm.beta` function coefficients value will match.

**2) Second Method:**

Here `QuantPsyc::lm.beta` can be used once you install QuantPsyc package which is for generating standardized betas like below.

```
QuantPsyc::lm.beta(lm(mpg ~ disp + wt + drat, data=mtcars))
```

Off-course apart from intercept(there is no sense of having intercept in standardized betas) both the results (via scaling and quantpsyc outcome) is matching here.